# What is the meaning of "to work my socks off"?

Tags: idioms

Would you please explain the meaning of "to work my socks off"?

example-

```
I'm working my socks off, and you're just sitting there doing nothing!
```

Thanks a million.

Comment: I appreciate Maulik.V answering your question, but well, why do you guys never try to google something before you approach the ell stack? if you had tried to search for "working my socks off" in google, yahoo etc you would have gotten the answer right off the bat(google for the meaning!). Asking for clarifications regarding usage or grammar is ok, but you are using ell stack like a dictionary, bad mate, bad.

Comment: I agree with @NANDA . Now, I also understand that sometimes dictionaries can be hard to navigate. The word _work_ has several meanings: we can work an audience, work some bread dough, or work a deal. I can work my socks off, laugh my socks off, rock my socks off, or take my socks off. There's plenty of room for confusion, and for questions to be asked here. But at least do some preliminary research first, and then [**share what you've discovered**](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working socks off means to work very hard to achieve something or finish the task.

> [to work [someone's] socks off](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/work+socks+off) - to work very hard

In your example, it means you are working very hard and the other person is just lying there doing nothing!

Another such idiom is to work your *tail* off.

Information [here](http://www.englishclub.com/ref/esl/Idioms/Quizzes/Body_9/work_your_socks_off_work_your_tail_off_714.htm).

Comment: @GirishK That's okay. No need to thank us. We are here to help others. Nevertheless, a little suggestion, next time, when you post any question, search on the Internet for the same. You may get the answer.